# List all Custom Post Type posts excluding certain Taxnomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop

I'm writing a theme in which I've registered "Services" as Custom Post Type that supports "Type of Service" Custom Taxonomy.

I want to list all the posts of type "Services" except those which have "Featured" as "Type of Service" term set. I can write code to list the Posts that are under specific Taxonomy term; but how to write wp_query that will exclude posts from certain Custom Taxonomy term?

Waiting for your reply...

Cheers,

\r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `NOT IN` value of the `operator` argument of a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Depending on your situation, you should use either [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Your tax_query would then look something like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => '{your taxonomy slug}',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'featured',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. This worked for me; I didn't know the "operator" parameter.